# Is there a way to select all from one table, and join if possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to SQL and postgreSQL, so I don't know if this is an obvious question.
I have two tables: products and images. I need to somehow select all products, and if it exists, their thumbnail from the images table.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ....
);

CREATE TABLE product_files (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products(ID),
  is_thumbnail BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  ...
);


SELECT p.id as product_id, p.status, p.title, p.description, pf.id, pf.file_name, pf.is_thumbnail
FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_files pf
ON p.id=pf.product_id
WHERE pf.is_thumbnail=true;
```

But i can't get it to select all of the products, even the ones without an image with thumbnail=true.

Comment: If you remove WHERE pf.is_thumbnail=true, you should get what you want

Comment: Why are you using that "thumbnail=true" condition?

Comment: bc I don't want to select the other images, just the thumbnail or just the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is turning the outer join to an inner join, because non-matches are filtered out.

Just move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.id as product_id, p.status, p.title, p.description, pf.id, pf.file_name, pf.is_thumbnail
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     product_files pf
     ON p.id  =pf.product_id AND pf.is_thumbnail;
```

There is nothing wrong with having `= true`.  However, `is_thumbnail` is a boolean, so there is no reason for an explicit comparison either.

The general rule when filtering for `LEFT JOIN`s is to put the conditions in the *first* table in a `WHERE` clause.  And filtering conditions on subsequent tables in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Gordon, if he wants all products and their images if exist, does he need the "AND pf.is_thumbnail" condition?

Comment: Because then i would get the images where is_thumbnail=false too, right?

Comment: @Qoutroy `is_thumbnail` is identical to `is_thumbnail = true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the condition for the thumbnail out off the WHERE into the JOIN condition:

```
select ..
FROM products p 
  LEFT  JOIN product_files pf ON p.id=pf.product_id AND pf.is_thumbnail=true;
```